# How do I declare a line in a text file as a variable?

Tags: python, file, lines, readlines

For example, I have opened a text file and found a product that the user wants to "buy". The products are listed on a notepad text file, with the product name then a new line then the cost of the product, for example

```
radiators
0.50
fridge
0.50
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
product = input("What product would you like?")
userfile = open ("products.txt","r")
    lines = userfile.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        if product in (line):
            found = True
            print("Found " + line)
            print("This product is " + lines[i+1])
            print("This product costs " +lines[i+2])
```

I need to declare `lines[i+2]` as a variable so I can multiply it like an integer. Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: You don't need to declare it as a variable (what does that even mean?), you just need to convert the string to a number.

Comment: okay thank you, but how would I do that??

Comment: I don't use Python, but your code looks wrong anyway: If `product` is `"radiators"`, it would output `Found radiators` `This product is 0.50` `This product costs fridge`.

Comment: oh. i changed the program a bit before i put it on here - the real one doesn't work that way???? i kind of used an example

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

product = input("What product would you like?")

```
userfile = open ("products.txt","r")
lines = userfile.readlines()

for line in lines:
   line = line.rstrip('\n')
   if product in line:
        found = True
        print("Found " + line)
        print("This product is " + lines[i+1])
        print("This product costs " + int(lines[i+2]))
```

Comment: thank you for replying, I've tried to use "int" in the code a few times like you suggested but this error always comes up

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.50\n'

Comment: @mollyclare That's because `0.5` is not an integer.

Comment: ahh okay, maybe i can just change the numbers then.. sorry about this thank you very much